# Timeout awaiting 'request' for 5000ms throws 504

Tags: node.js, angular, timeout

While login into my angular application (with NodeJS as backend) i rarely encounter the following error which prevents the user from entering into the application instead throwing 504 gateway error

```
UNHANDLED ERROR: TimeoutError: Timeout awaiting 'request' for 5000ms
at timeoutHandler (C:\myproject\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\utils\timed-out.js:36:25)
```

Can someone explain what does the error implies and how can i get rid of this error .

Comment: You have to share your backend endpoint code and front-end HTTP call script.

Comment: @mubin986 can you please explain when we get this error ?

Comment: It's happening because there is a pre-defined maximum delay or, timeout in the request which is 5000ms. If the operation has not been done before 5000ms, then it will automatically throw an error after that time. Because the program will not try forever to do that specific operation.

Comment: @mubin986 in that case do we need to increase the timeout ? Is there could be any specific reason why the request was not processed within the specific time .. because it rarely happens not all the time.

Comment: I don't know why it's not completing the request within 5000ms. For this, I've to see your codebase. That's why I was asking for that. And yes, you can increase timeout time.